# How to SUM each column value of a data table

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

How to sum each column value and to display the total sum value in Total Column for the below data using LINQ. SUM should not round the resultant.

```
Location    FY_Quarter  .NET    java     SAP    Total
Bangalore    Q3          40      60      40     140
Bangalore    Q4          50      80      30     
Bangalore    Q1          70      50      40     
Bangalore    Q2          30      90      50     
Chennai      Q3          80      40      60     
Chennai      Q4          45      50      35     
Chennai      Q1          60      75      65     
Chennai      Q2          55      35      90
```

Example for

```
Bangalore  Q4   50   80   30    160
```

Under `Total` it should show the value as  `160`

How to get??

Comment: Is Total part of the class ? can't it be calculated on the underlyings ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a calculated column:

```
table.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(int), "[.NET] + java + SAP");
```

Comment: I dont want to add freshly a new column as total in the  exisiting Datatable. SInce already 'Total' column is there in my Datatable

Comment: And where does this column come from? Did you add it with the designer? In this case, just set its `Expression` property to `"[.NET] + java + SAP"`

Comment: this column comes from database. But still it didn't have any data currently. And also the above numeric data is in string format. Please provide working code.

Comment: @sukumar, in that case you have to do the calculation manually... something like `row["Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row[".NET"]) + Convert.ToDecimal(row["java"]) + Convert.ToDecimal(row["SAP"])`

Answer (score 0):

The Total column shouldn't already be in the table itself. This could lead to all sorts of incorrect data.

You should either be looking at programmatically totalling the values in your LINQ/C# code or creating a **view** which has the Total as a calculated column.